# Processing form with Yesod and using the inputs to create something defined in models

Tags: forms, haskell, yesod

The crux of the action is in this file:

https://github.com/gdoteof/exodus/blob/42c5ee09f09dcb718fa3bdfd79bfe5182c03faaa/Handler/GamingSession.hs

The general idea that I am going for is to accept POSTED input, and use that input, combined with the UTCTime from getCurrentTime to create a new GamingSession.

Then the GamingSession would be inserted into the database.

What's happening now at /session is a form that posts to /session, with prefilled in values.  But I am getting an error

> Prelude.read: no parse

(relevant config/routes: https://github.com/gdoteof/exodus/blob/d07bea21e7699b44739ceadf3c3a18533a9ef462/config/routes
)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changing

```
textToKey = Key . PersistText . read . unpack
```

to

```
textToKey a = fromJust . fromPathPiece $ a
```

fixed it for me

Answer (score 1):

When I have a form for persist keys, I usually prefer a drop down rather than manual entry.  Try the code below.  Also, try to follow the idiomatic style in the book, it will help.

```
gs <- runInputPost $ GamingSession
            start
            Nothing
            <$> ireq (selectField (optionsPersistKey [] [] (toPathPiece . entityKey))) "player"
            <*> ireq (selectField (optionsPersistKey [] [] (toPathPiece . entityKey))) "table"
            <*> iopt intField "seat"

-- | The optionsPersist builtin to the Yesod.Forms package unfortunately only
--   works well with whole persist entities.  We are only interested in the entity
--   id s which is why we add in this function here:
optionsPersistKey
  :: (YesodPersist master
     , PersistEntity a
     , PersistQuery (YesodPersistBackend master) (GHandler sub master)
     , PathPiece (Key (YesodPersistBackend master) a)
     , RenderMessage master msg
     , PersistEntityBackend a ~ YesodPersistBackend master) 
  => [Filter a] 
  -> [SelectOpt a] 
  -> (Entity a -> msg) 
  -> GHandler sub master (OptionList (Key (PersistEntityBackend a) a))
optionsPersistKey filts ords toDisplay = fmap mkOptionList $ do
    mr <- getMessageRender
    pairs <- runDB $ selectList filts ords
    return $ map (\(Entity key value) -> Option
        { optionDisplay = mr (toDisplay $ Entity key value)
        , optionInternalValue = key
        , optionExternalValue = toPathPiece key
        }) pairs
```

Comment: I appreciate this.  THe form I built is just for testing.  In the end the input is the only part that will still be there.

The values will be submitted via javascript in the end

Comment: Handler/GamingSession.hs:51:31:
    Couldn't match expected type `Char' with actual type `Entity t0'
    In the pattern: Entity key value
    In the first argument of `Data.Text.map', namely
      `(\ (Entity key value)
          -> Option
               {optionDisplay = mr (toDisplay $ Entity key value),
                optionInternalValue = key, optionExternalValue = toPathPiece key})'
    In the second argument of `($)', namely
      `Data.Text.map
         (\ (Entity key value)
            -> Option
                 ...

Answer (score 1):

You're getting a read fail b/c you're trying to read values like "4f6150251c21230c78000000" to PersistInt64. The MongoDB backend does not use PersistInt64s for key values so that code won't build a proper key for your setup. I'd try PersistText.

Comment: Please note, the return value from textField will be Text so you won't need an unpack or read in textToKey, just `Key . PersistText`

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting means the input does not look like a normal integer. What do the prefilled values actually look like? The strings from `ireq textField "player"` and `ireq textField "table"` have to *just* contain a number possibly padded with whitespace.

Also, to make handling bad parses easier, you should look at the [safe package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/safe-0.3.3). This contains a version of `read` (and similar functions) that returns a `Maybe`, so you get a `Nothing` instead of an exception if it can't parse the input.

Comment: The values look like "4f6150251c21230c78000000" which is an id from mongo

Answer (score 0):

Ok, try this:

```
import Data.Text (unpack)

...

(player, table, seat) <- runInputPost $ (,,)
            <$> (ireq textField "player")
            <*> (ireq textField "table")
            <*> iopt intField "seat"
playerId <- maybe (invalidArgs ["couldn't parse: ", player]) return $ fromPathPiece player
tableId <- maybe (invalidArgs ["couldn't parse: ", table]) return $ formPathPiece table
let gs = GamingSession start Nothing playerId tableId seat 
...
```